# showing different images depending on id's

Tags: javascript, mootools

Files can be found at:

http://www.mediafire.com/?mhdbwy4gb4rfk4r

I have :

```
alert(this.internal.questionIndex);
```

This displays 0, 1, 2, 3 depending on what questions your on.

i now want to show a different image on each question.

```
 if (this.internal.questionIndex === 0) 

 {

     var myimg = new Element('img', {src:'images/q1.png'}); 


 }
```

thou this doesn't seem to work, any ideas folks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
var id = parseInt(this.internal.questionIndex, 10) + 1; //if for 0 you are using 1
var myimg = new Element('img', {src:'images/q' + id + '.png'});
```

Comment: glad to know it worked for you, you can mark it as accepted answer if it suited your needs...:)